# Spherical coordinates - triple integral boundary problem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

$$\left( \frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{z}{c} \right)^3 \le 1$$

$$x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0$$

So I made the following substitution using **spherical coordinates**

$x = ar\cos^2{\phi}\sin{\theta}$

$y = br\sin^2{\phi}\sin{\theta}$

$z = cr^{\frac{2}{3}}cos^{\frac{2}{3}}{\theta}$

where $\theta \in [0, \pi]$, $\phi \in [0, 2\pi]$

I think I chose the correct substitution because I get that $r^2 \le 1$, but here's the problem. Regarding the boundaries of the angles, if I substitute into $x,y,z \ge 0$ I get

$\cos^2{\phi}\sin{\theta} \ge 0$

$\sin^2{\phi}\sin{\theta} \ge 0$

$\cos^{\frac{2}{3}}{\theta} \ge 0$

From the last equation I can deduce that the boundaries for $\theta$ are $ \theta \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$

Let's try the same for $\phi$ in the first two equations:

Since $\theta$ is in the first quadrant, both cosine and sine are positive. **Taking a look at $\phi$, because each function containing $\phi$ is squared and thus is positive for any angle in its domain**, **does that mean we take the natural boundaries for** $\phi$, **which are** $\phi \in [0, 2\pi]$?

Comment: Are you sure that's a cube on the $z$ term, and the squares are not separate, as then the question would relate to an ellipsoid that can be categorised in the first octant.

Comment: @fundamentalform yes I double checked.